# Calculate the Marginal Probability

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

Given the following $$f(X_1, X_2 \mid p_1, p_2) = p_1^{x_1} (1 - p_1)^{({n_1}-{x_1})}p_2^{x_2}(1-p_2)^{({n_2}-{x_2})},$$ where

$p_1 \sim Unif(0,1)$ independently $p_2 \sim Unif(0,1)$, $n_1=34$ and $n_2 = 56$.

I need to calculate the marginal probability $P(X_1=27, X_2=20)$.

Comment: I am not sure what $f$ is. Is it a p.m.f.? Does it sum up to one?

Comment: It is equal to the likelihood L($p1$, $p2$)

Comment: It misses $\binom{n_1}{x_1}$ and $\binom{n_2}{x_2}$.

Comment: We were told to ignore the multiplicative constant to make the calculations easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use $f(X_1,X_2)=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(X_1,X_2|p_1,p_2)dp_1dp_2$ and then you may want to take a look at [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function):
$$
\int_0^1 p_1^{x_1}(1-p_1)^{n_1-x_1}dp_1=B(x_1+1,n_1-x_1+1)=\frac{x_1!(n_1-x_1)!}{(n_1+1)!}.
$$